# Importing a Library into an IntelliJ Project and Accessing it in Separate Class File

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, import

I searched StackOverflow and could not find the answer to my question.

I need to import a class that is in the directory codelibraries>chp10>Course.class

and use its various methods in a separate main class. I am having issues. Ive tried Project Structure > Libraries > then adding said directory. It shows up under the external libraries but I am unable to access the class file. In fact, the following code does not even work

import.codelibraries.chp10.Course;

Google hasn't even helped. Maybe I just didn't dig deep enough.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `import.codelibraries.chp10.Course;` is not valid syntax.

Comment: True. But even with the proper syntax it doesn't work. I'm tempted to ditch this IDE and just go back to text editor + command prompt. This is ridiculous. With JGrasp all I have to do is put the Course.class file in the same directory as the main class file and it works properly. No complicated hoops to jump through.